# Base 64 string magically gets bigger.. sometimes

Tags: javascript, loops, base64

I'm dealing with the strangest issue. I have a big string (about 5 million bytes) which I'm trying to shrink down. Before I shrink it, I'm trying to 'reconstruct' it as such:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var bb64 = "";
    var sb64 = "";

    //the big-ass string (~5 million bytes)
    bb64 = data[i];
    //initially one sixth of the big-ass string
    sb64 = bb64.substring(0, bb64.length/6);

    var start = bb64.length/6;
    var end = bb64.length;

    //for testing, re-add the remaining 5/6 characters
    for(var x = start; x < end; x++){
      sb64 += bb64[x]
    }

    //theoretically, these should be the same for each iteration of i
    console.log(bb64.length);
    console.log(sb64.length);

   /*actual results:
   i = 0:
   bb64:5458944
   sb64:5458944

   i = 1:
   bb64:5563292
   sb64:42651908

   i = 2:
   bb64:5555276
   sb64:42590452
   */  
  }
```

I then tested it with other big-ass strings (~3 million bytes), and the results were:

```
i = 0:
bb64:3132968
sb64:24019424

i = 1:
bb64:3635916
sb64:3635916

i = 2:
bb64:3791560
sb64:29068632
```

Anyone have *any* clue what the heck is going on..?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't round the value of length/6 ? You go beyond number maximum ?

Comment: hahahha what the heckk!! i just rounded and it worked. that really shouldn't make a difference though - look at the size difference, it's an order of magnitude! please post this as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @Jona, it makes a huge difference, wether you try to access the property "2" of a String-object, or wether you try to get "2.5". The first one will return a char, the latter will return undefined, wich are 9 chars as a string

Comment: @Thomas gotcha, makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "length/6" division is not rounded, using a non-rounded value as key have unpredictable results.

Comment: the result is very predictable, it "replaces" every char in the loop (the last 5 sixth of the input) with "undefined", aka 9 characters. `Math.floor(5563292/6) + Math.ceil(5563292*5/6) * 9 === 42651908`

Comment: @Thomas Right! I was typing exactly the same!